# Installing bootstrap-web-components to polymer

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, polymer, bower-install

**I am playing with polymerjs.**

**Goal**

I want to create a custom element using [polymerjs](https://www.polymer-project.org/) with bootstrap modal dialog encapsulated in this custom element. The clean solution seems to be to use [mike costello's bootstrap-web-components](https://github.com/MikeCostello/bootstrap-web-components)

boostrap-modal.html

```
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/bootstrap-web-components/dist/imports.html">

<polymer-element name="bootstrap-modal" attributes="script css">
    <template>
        <bs-modal title="Title" show="false">
            Dialog Contents
        </bs-modal>
    </template>

    <script>
    </script>
</polymer-element>
```

**Problem**

I used bower to install the library. My project has the root Polymer and in this folder resides the *index.html* file, *bower.json* file and a folder *bower_components*. My *bootstrap* and *bootstrap-web-components* folders reside in the bower_components folder. I import the bootstrap-web-components imports.html file only in my custom element.

Upon running, I get an **Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function** on the 13th line of bootstrap-web-components.js

**Thank you for your help!**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Back when the repo was created in 2013 polymer used `register()` this has changed to `registerElement()`. I've updated the repo and Bower package accordingly.

To import first make sure your site has the HTMLImports & CustomElements polyfills now at http://webcomponents.org

Then you can `<link rel="import" href="dist/imports.html">`

For a working example view source at http://mikecostello.github.io/bootstrap-web-components